# Location for Changing HTML in WordPress Site Page Files

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site that contain a custom theme from the following: http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/basic/

One thing I did was make a backup of the site so I could be safe testing around with the pages. There is is a section of code that I would like to change, but I cannot access the actual code. Here's a piece of the source from the template link:

```html
<nav id="navigation" class="grid-70 hide-on-tablet hide-on-mobile ">
  <ul id="menu-main" class="menu"><li  class="ut-home-link"><a href="#top" class="">Home</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="/#section-about-brooklyn" class="">About</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="/#section-our-team" class="">OUR TEAM</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="/#section-our-service" class="">Service</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="/#section-work" class="">WORK</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="/#section-happy-clients-2" class="">Clients</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/basic/blog/" class="">Blog</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children "><a href="/#section-elements" class="">Elements</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
 <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/basic/typography/" class="">Typography</a></li>
 <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/basic/common-elements-2/" class="">Common Elements</a></li>
 <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/basic/interactive-elements/" class="">Interactive Elements</a></li>
 <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/basic/icon-variants/" class="">Icon Variants</a></li>
 <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/wpversions/brooklyn/basic/media/" class="">Media</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <li  class="contact-us menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom "><a href="/#section-contact" class="">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Emphasis on is on the last `<li class="contact-us">` tag.

Now in my site's source, that same last tag I believe is the source of my grief, and I cannot link to my contact page properly due to `#section-content` not working. It looks like this:

```html
<li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page "><a href="http://scratchholler/contact-us/" class="">Contact</a></li>
```

It's missing the `"contact-us"` portion, and is `menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page` instead of `menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom`.  I've played around in the Dashboard with the Menus and all to no avail. Where in the WordPress PHP files can I fix this? WP-Admin? I want to manually edit the `#section-` areas. I'm lost. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you given, it can be inferred that the code you are taking about is the code of the WordPress menu. WordPress menu is normally called from the `header.php` in your themes folder.

You can customize the WordPress menu referring the link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu.

If you want to edit `header.php` from WordPress admin side please follow `Dashboard` > `Appearance` > `Editor` and edit `header.php`.